# Wals chapter 3 consonant vowel ratio

Tags: phonology, linguistic-typology

hello I just do not understand how to calculate consonant-vowel ratio referring wals chapter 3! I need to calculate the consonant-vowel ratio regarding german french and turkish! Concerning the alphabeth german and french have 21 consonants and 5 vowels and turkish has 21 consOnants and 8 vowels, however there are 3  umlauts in german and the amounts of consonants and vowels may vary in these 3 languages concerning complex combinations! Still just looking at the alphabeth can someone make the calculations and explain the values on wals regarding these 3 languages? Thanks and best regards!

(Hey I may be blocked and may not be able to comment on my question! Can you please show me how to calculate in one of these languages? Thanks!)

Comment: You can't count the number of phonological vowels in a language by looking at the alphabet. From what I remember, the authors of chapter 3 included a section describing their methodology.

Comment: Blocking occurs when you have too many low-quality questions. The way to get un-blocked is to edit your older questions based on feedback you have received.

Comment: Look at the introduction of chapter 2 to get an idea of how they decided on the values for vowel quality inventories: http://wals.info/chapter/2

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing difficult with the concept: the ratio of X to Y is X/Y. If you want to know the consonant-to-vowel quality ratio of Turkish, you need to know the number of consonants in Turkish, and the number of vowel qualities in Turkish. According to the map and definitions in ch. 1, Turkish has an average number of consonants, defined as 22±3, and a large set of vowel qualities, which is 7-14. Turkish is reported to have an average C/VQ ratio, defined as 2.75 or higher but less than 4.5.

Rather than computing such a ratio, you can just look up the ballpark of the ratio. If you want to actually compute an exact number, you have to decide what values you want to assign for C and VQ. The counting criteria are not clearly spelled out in the articles: the procedure is "Long and short variants of the same vowel are always counted once, nasalized vowels do not add to the inventory as long as a non-nasalized counterpart occurs, *and so on*" (that is, one is free to add similar criteria, if you want). There are in fact 8 vowels in Turkish (though earlier the author reported 9), so that part is not wildly controversial. In some other language, this could be utterly unclear, for example is the English seat / sit distinction a length distinction (some people say so) or a quality distinction (some people say so)? What about phonatory differences in Otomanguean or Nilotic, or tones of Vietnamese (which are a mix of pitch and phonation)?

As for the consonant-counting methodology, Ch. 1 states

> a strong effort has been made to apply consistent criteria in
>   determining the consonant inventory size. This sometimes leads to some
>   difference from the conclusions in published descriptions of the
>   languages concerned. For most languages relatively straightforward
>   decisions can be reached, but others are more problematic. A difficult
>   choice often concerns whether to include consonants found only in
>   words borrowed from other languages; generally those sounds introduced
>   just in the last few generations as the result of the spread of world
>   languages such as English, Spanish, Russian, Mandarin, and Modern
>   Standard Arabic have been excluded.

If you take the [Wiki article on Turkish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_phonology#Consonants), there are 24 consonants, with 3 of them being somewhat marginal; the C/VQ ratio for Turkish is thus between 3 and 3.42857. Ch. 1 does not explain any special criteria for consonant-counting, so the fact that Turkish has geminate consonants could mess with the count, though obviously given the report that Turkish has an average count of consonants, we can surmise that the author did not include geminate consonants, at least in counting Turkish. The palatal consonants of Turkish are both "predictable" and phonemic. The discussion in Ch. 1 implies that allophonic variants are not included (so aspiration in English does not bump up the count); possible the flap [ɾ] is excluded as being always derived, but this is controversial (given "capitalistic" vs. "militaristic"). Counting issues will also arise depending on whether [mp, mb, nt, nd...] are analyzed as clusters of [m, b, p, n, d, t] or as independent "prenasalized" consonants. The procedure is, as far as I know, to accept the analysis of the original source author unless there is a good reason to disbelieve. There is no discussion of actual numbers for particular languages.

One might, however, probe deeper by looking at UPSID, which gives phoneme lists for specific languages. The Turkish UPSID phoneme list is [here](http://web.phonetik.uni-frankfurt.de/L/L2158.html), which reports 9 vowels and 25 consonants. Inspecting the set of languages reported to have "long consonants", 12 languages are said to have them. Turkish, Finnish, Arabic, Japanese are included in the UPSID language set, all actually have long consonants, and none of these languages are reported as having long consonants. The discrepancy may be explained by some theory of consonant length in e.g. Wolof, Archi, Avar (which are said to have long consonants) and the many other languages which do have long consonants but are not reported in UPSID as having them.

From a scientific POV, C/VQ ratio should be considered to be a range, rather than a precise computation, for reasons that should be clear.